# How to print only to ages of people in a list?

Tags: python

So I have a list of teams and I want to only print the ages of the people in the team. This is my code:

```
teams = [
[("Mustapha",12),("Olivier",13),("Jean-Paul",10),("Loic",11)],
[("Georges",12),("Sandrine",14),("Alain",13)],
[("Jean-Francois",13),("Armelle",10)]
]

def age(teams):
    for team in teams:
        for member in team:
            for (name,age) in member:
                print(age)

age(teams)
```

I keep getting this error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

I'm not really sure what's wrong as for each member there are only two values (name and age).

Comment: `for team in teams: for name, age in team: print(age)` — One loop too many.

Comment: I see, thanks alot I will try that out

Answer (score 1):

You use one extra loop, just do:

```
teams = [
[("Mustapha",12),("Olivier",13),("Jean-Paul",10),("Loic",11)],
[("Georges",12),("Sandrine",14),("Alain",13)],
[("Jean-Francois",13),("Armelle",10)]
]

def age(teams):
    for team in teams:
        for (name,age) in team:
            print(age)

age(teams)
```

Output:

```
12
13
10
11
12
14
13
13
10
```

The reason why you had an extra loop is because the first loop goes and gets the teams separate, and the second loop goes and gets every person separate, but then that means the next loop has to iterate through only 2 items every time, so if you want three loops, use:

```
teams = [
[("Mustapha",12),("Olivier",13),("Jean-Paul",10),("Loic",11)],
[("Georges",12),("Sandrine",14),("Alain",13)],
[("Jean-Francois",13),("Armelle",10)]
]

def age(teams):
    for team in teams:
        for member in team:
            for age in member[1:]:
                print(age)

age(teams)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for third loop. The code should be something like this:

```
teams = [
    [("Mustapha", 12), ("Olivier", 13), ("Jean-Paul", 10), ("Loic", 11)],
    [("Georges", 12), ("Sandrine", 14), ("Alain", 13)],
    [("Jean-Francois", 13), ("Armelle", 10)],
]


def age(teams):
    for team in teams:
        for member in team:
            print(member[1])


age(teams)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use list comprehension

```
def age(teams):
    age_list = [age for team in teams for (name,age) in team]
    return age_list


for age in age(teams):
    print(age)
```

Output

```
13
10
11
12
14
13
13
10
```

Answer (score 0):

You added an extra loop for no reason. Once you got the member tuple in the second loop, you could just use indexing to choose which part of the tuple you wanted to use. Age in this case would be the second part of the tuple, which would be given by using member[1].

```py
teams = [
[("Mustapha",12),("Olivier",13),("Jean-Paul",10),("Loic",11)],
[("Georges",12),("Sandrine",14),("Alain",13)],
[("Jean-Francois",13),("Armelle",10)]
]

def age(teams):
    for team in teams:
        for member in team:
            print (member[1])
            # member[1] is the age and member[0] is the name.

age(teams)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line `for (name, age) in member:` you are trying to iterate over a member, but what you really want is to unpack the member into `name` and `age`.

```py
teams = [
[("Mustapha",12),("Olivier",13),("Jean-Paul",10),("Loic",11)],
[("Georges",12),("Sandrine",14),("Alain",13)],
[("Jean-Francois",13),("Armelle",10)]
]

def age(teams):
    for team in teams:
        for member in team:
            name, age = member # I changed this line
            print(age)

age(teams)
```